# Is it possible to convert body of a method to string?

Tags: c#, string

I'm wondering if it's possible to convert body of a method into a string. We are going to run some scripts with algorithms stored in database.

What I mean is, for example, algorithm:

```
 "var x = 4; return x + 5;"
```

I would like to be able to test this algorithm before and I would like to have the method in a more standard way:

```
 public int GetResult()
 {
  var x = 4;
  return x + 5; 
  }
```

My question is, is it possible to write something like 
GetResult().ToString(); that would return the body of the GetResult() method?

```
   "var x = 4;return x + 5;"
```

I am aware that probably such method doesn't exist but if I would have to write some extension, I'd like to try it. I just want to know if it's possible and in what way I should go.

Perhaps reading a .cs file and loading content, then somehow selecting my method would work?

Comment: C# code does not execute in database (oracle, sql server, etc) because they have different syntax.

Comment: You'd be better advised to go the other way around: Start with a string, then compile it.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples